# Custom dynamic success message after submit page apex

Tags: oracle-apex

How i can return  dynamic success messages after submit page.
The message like " the deal create successfully your deal number tah-01-01-0001 " 
Note the region type it's form, and i have column, the value for this column generate in database trigger like this value "tah-01-01-0001" the last four value '0001'  changed sequencally  i want to appear this value in message, how i can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The success message is allowed to refer to page items using substitution syntax, e.g.

```
The deal was created successfully. Your deal number is &P1_DEAL_NO.
```

You would just need to ensure that your PL/SQL process does set the page item value (e.g. `P1_DEAL_NO` in this example).

Comment: Thanks, but the process doesn't return the value in item,  only saved in table by trigger in database ,( i used automatic form DML process ), how i can return this value in item.

Comment: @jaw You could always rewrite the automatic process.

Comment: Look in the DML process for a setting like "Return Primary Key(s) after Insert". Ensure that's enabled. If that's not the value P1_DEAL_NO, then you should at least be able to use the primary key to fetch the value for P1_DEAL_NO after the DML process does the insert.